# Do we have Pivot Table control in react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

Do we have Pivot Table control in react-bootstrap?
I could not find in official website 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

Can anybody guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table control is not available in react-bootstrap. Neither is one listed in the docs you point out and in the codebase itself on Github. No mention of the control in their Bootstrap4 [roadmap either](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1187)